Share cookies or session data between cross domain using ASP.NET C#
We have a shared state management server and aim to transfer session values between two domains: modern.com and 180algos.com. Both domains redirect to a common page, freelogin.aspx, which is hosted exclusively on modern.com. On this page, I need to retrieve the session["sitename"] value.
For example:

modern.com/password.aspx stores session["sitename"] = "V3".
180algos.com/login.aspx stores session["sitename"] = "360algos".
Without using a redirect or query string, we access freelogin.aspx directly, such as https://modern.com/freelogin.aspx. On this page, I need to identify the originating site and handle the session value accordingly.

freelogin.aspx.cs
if (session["sitename"] == "V3")
{
    // From the modern site 
}
else if (session["sitename"] == "360algos")
{
    // From the 180algos site
}

How can I implement this functionality in ASP.NET using alternative approaches, such as sessions, cookies, or JWTs?
If I access the page directly using https://modern.com/freelogin.aspx, the stored session value should be retrieved.
Note :-

Should not use any redirection/query string ex:- Response.Redirect("https://freelogin.aspx?sitename=V3");
Is it possible to transfer data across different domains?


jsonp? load javascript from the other domain, the script should call a function from your domain and can pass any data as an argument. (or just set CORS headers properly...). Just like OAuth, you shouldn't trust the browser and should connect between servers to verify any information.

@JeremyLakeman Sir, thank you for your comment. However, I didn’t fully understand it. Could you please share some sample code or an example link to help me gain a clearer understanding?

You can pass data via the browser using fetch() or <script. With the right CORS headers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), you can access that data and redirect or post it back to this server. But you also need a mechanism to verify the origin and consistency of that data. Because anyone can manipulate their own browser to give you anything they want.

eg fetch(new Request("https://domain1/who_are_you.json", { credentials: "include" })) ... Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domain2   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Can't you use the value of the referer header? This should contain the page that you are coming from. You could check the domain and based on that decide where the user comes from. I doubt you want to do this with session variables/cookies.
Obviously the most reliable/foolproof method would be the one you ruled out: using query parameters.
In case you want more information, here you can read up on the referer header:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer
Keep in mind anyone can manipulate the value of this header.
